# C Structures inserção feita mas não consigo ler

Tags: c, struct

tenho uma struct

```c
typedef struct
   {
       int id;
       char nome[50];
       int tipoUser;
       float vencimentos;
       int id_clinica;
   
   } Utilizador;
```

na qual insiro valores através do seguinte código:

```c
void criarCliente(Utilizador *utilizador, int n)
{

    printf("NOME: ");
    fgets(utilizador->nome, 50, stdin);
    utilizador->nome[strlen((utilizador->nome) - 1)] = '\0';

    printf("Vencimentos: ");
    scanf("%f", &utilizador->vencimentos);

    printf("tipo de user(1-Medico,2-Enfermeiro,3-Funcionario) ");
    scanf("%d", &utilizador->tipoUser);
    utilizador->id = n + 1;
    printf("id da clinica a que está associada ");
    scanf("%d", &utilizador->id_clinica);
}
boolean inserirCliente(Utilizador *utilizadores, int *n, Utilizador utilizador)
{
    if (*n > TAMUtilizador)
    {
        return false;
    }
    utilizadores[*n] = utilizador;
    (*n)++;
listarClientesAtivos(utilizadores,*n);

    return true;
    
}
```

a minha função listarClientesAtivos:

```
void listarClientesAtivos(Utilizador *utilizadores,int n)
{
  
     system("cls");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      
            printf("%d id =|", utilizadores[i].id);
            printf("%s  NOME =|", utilizadores[i].nome);
            printf("%f VENCIMENTOS=|", utilizadores[i].vencimentos);
            printf("%d IDCLINICA=|\n", utilizadores[i].id_clinica);
            
       
    }
}
```

em vez de retronar os clientes inseridos, retorna :

> 1 id =|  NOME =|0 VENCIMENTOS=|1073741824 IDCLINICA=|

Gostaria de perceber qual o meu erro

Comment: Você definiu tipoUser; como int então troque `scanf("%f", &utilizador->tipoUser);` por `scanf("%d", &utilizador->vencimentos);`. Idempara `id_clinica`. `vencimentos` é float então troque `printf("%d VENCIMENTOS=|", utilizadores[i].vencimentos);` por `printf("%f VENCIMENTOS=|", utilizadores[i].vencimentos);`. Aliás estes seus printf estão confusos, o valor não deveria estar **após** o texto?

Comment: estão confusos sim, porque era so para ver onde seria printado aquele valor de forma rudimentar, a ideia original é mesmo so ter "|" ,  de qualquer das formas alterei o que voce disse e funciona, tudo menos a string "nome" ...